# Azure Data Factory - Azure DevOps - The assigned "user assigned managed identity" for target ADF gets removed when deploying to it, failing deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template, azure-managed-identity

I have two environments for the ADF, the "Dev" and "UAT".

I have **assigned** both of the environments to the same "User Assigned Managed Identity" that I use in my credential to authenticate target sources.

Dev Assigned Managed Identity

[image]

UAT Assigned Managed Identity before the deployment

[image]

It works as expected in the "Dev" environment, and the question is not about how to use managed identity. The problem is when I try to deploy the ARM template to "UAT" through the Azure DevOps release pipeline and the deployment fails.

I have identified exactly why that is happening but can't figure out how to overcome the problem.

Essentially the deployment step drops the assigned "User Assigned Managed Identity" from the "UAT" Data Factory settings.

UAT Managed Identities after deployment

[image]

As a result, because the UAT ADF environment does not have it, the deployment fails with the following error.

Error

[image]

Essentially saying, in the UAT Environment, there is no "User Assigned Managed Identity" associated with the factory and the credential is unable to find it and use it.

I use ARM Template Deployment V 3.*

ARM Template Deployment

[image]

The deployment mode used is "Incremental"

Forgot to mention, the CI/CD ADF Pipeline has been set up and I have been using it for a while, the issue with deployment started only when I tried to utilise managed identities instead of keys.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the origin of the problem as well as the solution.

Even though I have assigned both "System Assigned Managed Entity" and "User Assigned Managed Identity" against the "Dev" environment, the "Dev" ARM template still defaulted its parameter value at only "System Assigned Managed Entity"

[System Assigned Managed Entity Parameter Inside the ARM Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DW5Y.png)

Hence, when publishing, the said parameter would get picked up and remove the UAMI I have set up previously.

There are a few ways to approach it but the one I used was to change the contents of the ARMTemplateForFactory.json.

Step 1. Add an extra parameter in the "Parameters": {}

```
        "uamiName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "YourUamiHere"
    }
```

Step 2. Change "identity" from

```
            "identity": {
            "type": "[parameters('dataFactory_identity_type')]"
        }
```

To

```
            "identity": {
            "type": "SystemAssigned,UserAssigned",
            "userAssignedIdentities": {
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', parameters('uamiName'))]": {}
            }
        }
```

You can also then override template parameters in the ARM Template Deployment to use different UAMI in other environments.